# Struts 2 and Spring 4, how to get the validator or action object from spring application context

Tags: java, spring, configuration, struts2, struts-validation

We are using Struts 2.5 and Spring 4. The Struts is configured spring as mentioned in https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-and-struts-2.html.

The struts `actions` and `validators` are Spring managed beans and I can `inject` ( or `autowire`) other beans in them.

This validator is working fine which shows the validator is an spring bean:

```
public class MyValidator(){

    @javax.inject.Inject
    private HelperClass aHelperClass;
}
```

Now, i want to get the `MyValidator` class from spring application context and use it. The below codes did not worked and returned `null`

```
applicationContext.getBean("MyValidator");
applicationContext.getBean("foo.bar.MyValidator");
```

I look at `applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()` but could not find the `validator`.

So how can I get the Struts validator from spring `applicationContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bean is not configured in application context. You should add `@Component` annotation to let the Spring find this bean using component scan.

```
@Component
public class MyValidator(){

    @javax.inject.Inject
    private HelperClass aHelperClass;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RomanC I will test it soon (not at my PC right now!). By the way I guess that as the `inject` works in the `validators` and `actions` then `validators` and `actions` are already spring manage been and there is no need to re-annotate it. Am I wrong ?!

Comment: The `@Component` worked. (we used `@Named` which is some how the same)

Comment: Dear @RomanC I have still some question about struts beans. I asked it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706221/struts-2-and-spring-how-struts-created-objects-handled. I appreciate if you can have a look at it

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi I have remembered the new instance is created always by struts-spring plugin if the bean is not managed by Spring.