# Struts 2 and Spring how struts-created objects handled

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, struts2, integration

We are using Struts 2 with spring frame work 4 (https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html). I have some question about Struts bean creation.

When we use Struts with Spring we can easily use spring `@Inject`, `@Value`, `@Resource` in `Actions`, `Validators` and `Interceptors`, ***without*** annotating any of them as `@Component` (or `@Named`). This ***seems*** that struts-created objects are spring managed beans.

This is not true, because when you look at `applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()` you can not find any action, validator or interceptor.

So if Struts-created objects are not spring manage beans, why the spring annotations ( `@Inject`, `@Value`, ...) works quite well?

Is it technically possible that we create a new object (after spring start up) and pass it to Spring and let Spring setup it? How?!

Comment: *When an object is to be created, it uses the `class` attribute in the Struts configuration to correspond to the `id` attribute in the Spring configuration. If not found, the class will try to be created as usual, then be autowired by Spring.*

Comment: @AleksandrM What do you mean *as usual*?

Comment: As usual -> in the ordinary or expected way. Same like w/o spring plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Struts uses an `ObjectFactory` to build any object like actions, interceptors, validators, etc.:

> `ObjectFactory` is responsible for building the core framework objects. Users may register their
> own implementation of the `ObjectFactory` to control instantiation of these Objects.

[Struts-Spring plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/spring/) registers its own object factory `StrutsSpringObjectFactory`:

> Struts object factory that integrates with Spring.

There, it overrides methods building Objects, such as `buildBean()`.

Now if you look at the implementation, it is using method `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory#createBean()`

which generally creates a new instance of the clazz argument.

> Central method of this class: creates a bean instance,
> populates the bean instance, applies post-processors, etc.

Then, the newly created instance is passed for autowiring with `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory#autowireBeanProperties()`

After that, this instance is passed to Guice for injection.

Now it's fully *baked* and ready to return.

---

Note that, if the bean is managed by Spring, it uses `getBean` method from application context, otherwise the new instance is created always by struts-spring plugin if the bean is not managed by Spring.

Comment: The `AutowireCapableBeanFactory#autowireBeanProperties()` is the one which one which I was looking for. So the bean properties can be autowired by this factory even if they are not managed by spring. Thank you!

Comment: I think you have a typo in your answer, it should say 'this instance is passed to Spring for injection'.